# How to update multiple phone numbers using ContentProviderOperation

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

First, my contact insertion code:

```kotlin
    fun makeRawContact(): ContentProviderOperation.Builder {
        return ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, getString(R.string.account_type_contacts))
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName)
    }

    fun makeData(mimeType: String): ContentProviderOperation.Builder {
        return ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, mimeType)
    }

    fun insert(): Int {
        val ops = ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>()
        ops += makeRawContact().build()
        ops += makeData(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "testinsert")
            .build()

        ops += makeData(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, "12345678")
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, 1)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL, null)
            .build()

        val result = contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops)
    }
```

Suppose that the raw id is 8 by calling `insert()`.

If I want to update name of contact, I call like this:

```kotlin
    fun updateData(rawId: Long, mimeType: String): ContentProviderOperation.Builder {
        return ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?", arrayOf(rawId.toString()))
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, mimeType)
    }

    fun update() {
        val ops = ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>()
        ops += updateData(8, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "testupdate")
            .build()
        val result = contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops)
    }
```

I want to update two phone numbers on contact with raw id 8, but it has only one phone number `12345678`.
I think that one should be updated and the other should be inserted, so I'm trying to get data id of the phone number through `ContentResolver` and raw id. But this seems to be complex, so I ask question. Is there a better way? I've seen how to delete all and insert new phone numbers, but I believe there is a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're implementing a full blown contact editor that allows the user to **view and edit** info items then you should attach a flag to each row that says if that row was untouched/deleted/inserted/updated,
and then you iterate through the rows and update the DB accordingly.

If you're not doing something like that, the cleanest approach I've seen is to delete whatever existing phones there are in the DB for that raw-contact, and insert the new/updated ones.

Try to put both delete operation and insert operations into the same applyBatch call so there won't be any race conditions here with some other app / thread trying to update the same raw-contact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I implement contact editor, should I have the data ID(such as phone, email, event, ...), not the raw contact ID for flags?

Comment: that's your call, but that's how I would do it... update by `Data._ID` not by `RawContact._ID`

Comment: Actually, I'm implementing contacts synchronization app. The server only has `RawContact.SOURCE_ID`, so should I find `Data._ID` using it and update phone numbers like my question(update one, insert the other)?

Comment: if the server doesn't store the Data._ID you wouldn't know which one to update and which one to insert... you'll probably need to compare values which is not a good path... I would go with the delete-all-then-insert-new approach in this case

Comment: Regardless of which is updating and inserting, I was thinking about inserting and updating contact according to the size of the phone number list. When google sync-adapter synchronizes contacts, the ID of data table doesn't increase rapidly. So, I thought there is a good way to update... What do you think the google sync-adapter used to achieve this? Thanks for answering the boring questions.

Comment: I think google updates data by Data._ID, it probably stores data IDs somewhere to facilitate these updates.